# html select option have issue using angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I have this problem > http://jsfiddle.net/wwno55hj/109/  I want to stay only two string: true and false. if `$scope.readOnly = true;` in html selected must be True and if `$scope.readOnly = false;` in html selected must be False.

Comment: What do you exactly want? Because when I click true/false and I check my console it gives me the right output..

Answer (score 0):

`ngSelected` is to be used in `<option>` not `<select>`.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/wwno55hj/112/

Comment: You should remove `selected` from the `option` tabs if using `ng-selected`